# Extract -webkit-transform matrix3d values

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, css, 3d

I am trying to render 3D shapes using `<canvas>` (2d context), which means I have to perform some manual projective transformations.

It would help me a lot to be able to retrieve the 3D transformation matrix values from the CSS.

Can this be done?

If not, how can I construct the transformation that is performed by -webkit-perspective-origin? I've figured the transformation out for just the perspective alone, but that has the perspective origin at x=y=0 which is not always the case.

I realize that this specific case (perspective with origin at some point x, y, z) may turn out to be a simple x, y, z translation immediately followed by the perspective transform (or the other way around) but the ideal answer would be a method to extract the actual 4x4 3D matrix. If I have the matrix, I no longer have to re-trace the steps that I did to transform my CSS3 elements in order to apply the same transforms to geometry which I intend to render using `<canvas>`.

I looked here (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/) for reference but it does not look like they describe the actual values being assigned to the matrix when applying the different possible transformations. I think there should be some spec sheet out there that does go into such detail. I seem to recall even catching a glimpse of it (matrix definitions with lots of trig functions) somewhere.

Edit: I found a more in-depth overview of the steps the browser takes to perform the transformations [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/#transform-3d-rendering). Does not answer my question but it does get me one step closer to my temporary goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transform matrix of an element can be retrieved via getComputedStyle. Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kxxwu/

Another way would be to use WebKitCSSMatrix interface. Its very handy, it provides an object with matrix values and also some methods:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitCSSMatrixClassReference/WebKitCSSMatrix/WebKitCSSMatrix.html

The bad part is that WebKitCSSMatrix is not implemented in other browsers...

Would like to see how you are implementing 3d transform into canvas. A good place to peek would be three.js. They have did it and you can see various matrix functions there.

Good luck!

Comment: So it seems like the matrix value assigned to each element is the relative transform between it and its parent. I guess there's no way to get the cumulative transform other than manually multiplying the matrices together?

Comment: Took me a while to figure this one out. The 3d matrix spit out by getComputedStyle does not include the transform-origin x,y translation. I'm getting close to where I want to be...

Comment: I think that you should multiply the matrix according to transform-origin (X, Y, Z) and perspective.

Comment: transform-origin is a 2D value. It may not even be possible to set your transform origin to z!=0, however it wouldn't be too difficult to actually achieve: you can just nest with a z-translated element.

Comment: you have -webkit-transform-origin-z and moz-transform-origin that takes a 3rd value (x, y, x)

Comment: sorry that is -moz-transform-origin(x, y, z) in length and percentage. Of course you have a 3d value. Its just a point on a 3d Cartesian space.